# Undefined variable: users

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to show users in my view, but i have this error Undefined variable: users

I don't know what is the problem, because in my controller for that view the user method is called.

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User;
use App\Role;

use App\Http\Requests;

class pagesController extends Controller
{
    public function viewIndex(){
        $users = User::all();
        return view('index', ['users' => $users]);
        //return view('index');
    }
}
```

And this is the route where my controller is called

```html
Route::get('/index', [
        'uses' => 'pagesController@getIndex',
        'as' => 'admin',
        'middleware' => 'roles',
        'roles' => ['Admin']
    ]);
```

This is my blade file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Laravel Blog</title>
    <!-- CHANGE THIS TITLE FOR EACH PAGE -->

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Default Bootstrap Navbar -->
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
                      </ul>
                                      
                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                       @if (Auth::guest())
                            <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    @foreach($users as $user)
                                          
                                       @if($user->hasRole('Admin'))
                                    <li><a href="{{ url('/admin') }}">Edit users</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                    
                                   @else
                                    <li><a href="{{ url('/admin') }}">Edit page</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                   @endif
                                   @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Welcome to My Blog!</h1>
            <p class="lead">Thank you so much for visiting. This is my test website built with Laravel. Please read my popular post!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     

    </div>
    <!-- end of .container -->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show the code of blade file ?

Comment: I add the blade file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're pointing to wrong controller method in your routes.
Your route will be:

```
Route::get('/index', [
    'uses' => 'pagesController@viewIndex',
    'as' => 'admin',
    'middleware' => 'roles',
    'roles' => ['Admin']
]);
```

and your controller (pagesController) will go like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User;
use App\Role;

use App\Http\Requests;

class pagesController extends Controller
{
    public function viewIndex(){
        $users = User::all();
        return view('index', compact('users'));
    }
}
```

I think this will help to solve your problem.
Note: Please follow the naming conventions in your code so that it would be easy to understand and some frameworks (like laravel itself) runs on some followed conventions.
Thanks!